# Unable to Get Correct User Online Presence

Tags: facebook

I have an app in which I want to check my users' online presence. Right now, when I check, it tells me everyone is offline.

The users grant user_online_presence and offline_access (plus a few other) permissions to the app. Then I store the access token. I am able to access any information I need at any time except for the online presence.

To get the online presence, I first set the access token:

> $facebook->setAccessToken($user['AccessToken']);

Then I query Facebook:

> $fql = "SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status FROM user WHERE uid = ".$user['FacebookID'];
>   $param = array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql, 'callback' => '');
>   $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);

When I check the results, I get the id, name, and status, but everyone is listed as offline, even me when I know I'm online and active:

> [online_presence] => offline

Any help getting this working would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I used this FQL query sucessfully :-

```
SELECT name,online_presence FROM user WHERE uid 
IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

to get all the online friends. Got output as "idle","active" and "offline". All values of which were absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 permits

- user_online_presence, for the user
- friends_online_presence, for friends

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Thank you, I only need user_online_presence because I am only looking at when the user is online.

Answer (score 0):

online_presence is for chat online, not facebook online

> The user's Facebook Chat status. Returns a string, one of active,
>   idle, offline, or error (when Facebook can't determine presence
>   information on the server side). The query does not return the user's
>   Facebook Chat status when that information is restricted for privacy
>   reasons.

Also, I ran `fql?q=SELECT name, online_presence FROM user where uid IN (Select uid1 from friend WHERE uid2=me())` and it listed my friend's online status fairly accurately. Only a very few were incorrect.  Maybe that's due to a lag in the facebook update system, or maybe they're caching the information for too long, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking a user's user_online_presence when the user is not logged in through my app. That way I should be able to see if he is offline. I have seen a blank online status when privacy is set, so I know that is not the issue. I do not have chat privacy set on my account and my friends can see me online and available for chat, but users->online_presence is still returning me as offline all the time. It is the same for my other users.

Comment: `online_presence` is **only** for chat and has **nothing** to do with whether or not the user is logged into **your** app.

Comment: Thank you. I am **not** trying to find out if the user is logged in to **my** app, I am trying to find out if the user is logged in to Facebook and available for chat. So you agree that I should be able to use 'online_presence' to find this out. Unfortunately my problem still stands: I get **offline** no matter what. And I am online and I do not have chat privacy set.

Comment: As I said, for all of my friends from that FQL I posted above, 99% of the time Facebook is as accurate as the chat window statuses.  1% wrong for some users probably because of caching or latency in passing the information from one datastore to another.  And it is always wrong for me, no matter how many messages I sent via the chat, it always show the `me()` as being offline.

Comment: At least you are getting the same problem I am. Unfortunately I only need to know the online presence of our users, so I get that problem with all of them. I went ahead and reported it as a bug and we'll see if it gets a response.